# "Executed multiple catch exception strategy "

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I have choice exception strategy where I have multiple catch exception strategy there I am applying condition based on the error.

Error 1:

> org.mule.api.MessagingException: Column 'department_id' cannot be null (java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException).

Error 2:

> org.mule.api.MessagingException: org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mulesoft : Access denied for user 'root1212'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (java.sql.SQLException) (org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.DbConnectionException).

How can I differentiate between both of the error using expression in catch exception strategy?

First catch- Executed when:

> [exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException: Column 'department_id' cannot be null*")]

Second catch- Executed when:

> [exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException: org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException*")]

By using this not able to trigger into catch exception strategy.

> [exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException*")]

This is working but for both the error getting same starting string. How can i differentiate both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch specific exceptions based on the root cause. Use causedBy method on exception with the fully qualified exception name. Below examples handles 2 specific exceptions and then a default catch for all other exceptions.

```
 <choice-exception-strategy>
      <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(com.ricston.CustomException)">
        <!-- do stuff -->
      </catch-exception-strategy>
      <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException)">
        <!-- do stuff -->
      </catch-exception-strategy>
      <catch-exception-strategy>
        <!-- other exceptions. do stuff -->
      </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```