# “Executed multiple catch exception strategy”

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have choice exception strategy where I have multiple catch exception strategy there I am applying condition based on the error.
Error 1:

org.mule.api.MessagingException: Column 'department_id' cannot be null (java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException).

Error 2:

org.mule.api.MessagingException: org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mulesoft : Access denied for user 'root1212'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (java.sql.SQLException) (org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.DbConnectionException).

How can I differentiate between both of the error using expression in catch exception strategy?

First catch- Executed when:

## [exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException: Column 'department_id' cannot be null*")]

Second catch- Executed when:

## [exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException: org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException*")]

By using this not able to trigger into catch exception strategy.

[exception.causeMatches("org.mule.api.MessagingException*")]
This is working but for both the error getting same starting string. How can i differentiate both?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a double posting of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034753/executed-multiple-catch-exception-strategy

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Executed multiple catch exception strategy "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034753/executed-multiple-catch-exception-strategy)